# Streaming pdf bytes array from server to client part by part on only one requesst using Spring and Jquery

Tags: jquery, spring, pdf, streaming

Now I use spring on server and jquery on client to stream pdf file from server to client but i have many pdf files so at the beginning i merge them to one thing and finally send to client. However, due to have many files so it take time so much to get from DB to bytes array and merge them. Hence, I am finding a solution for this. My purpose, for example: i have 10 bytes array (10 pdf files), i want to send one by one to client, followed by each other. It means while i send first file to client then second one is got and send follow by it and go on for third, 4th ....If i can do that, i save time to send data from server to client.

Anyone have same problem or have the solution, please help me. I really need your help. Sorry for my english level. :)

Thanks,

Comment: please can you format question properly?

Comment: sorry, it's the first time i post question on this site. please tell me how can i format this properly. :)

Comment: their is a help provided in editor please check that.